# Create a python dictionary from a text file of variable columns

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

My basic requirement is to feed data to an API which creates and deletes users on a system.The API has its own format in which it will take the data.The API has 2 steps:

1. Connect to the system
2. Create/delete the user/users as per the data in the input file

The input data format is as follows:

```
Device1 192.168.1.2 NEW:jason:OPERATOR NEW:kylie:ADMINISTRATOR DELETE:ron:OPERATOR
Device2 10.12.34.12 NEW:kim:OPERATOR DELETE:joe:USER_ROLE_GUEST 
Device3 12.3.21.45 
Device4 8.21.34.25 DELETE:alex:USER_ROLE_GUEST
```

The API format is as follows(example for the first row of data):

```
b = bigsuds.BIGIP(hostname = '192.168.1.2', username = 'admin', password = 'letmein') 

b.Mgmt.UserMgmt.create_user([{'user': {'name': 'jason'}, 
                          'password': {'password': 'letmein'}, 
                          'permissions': [{'role': 'USER_ROLE_GUEST'}], 
                          'login_shell': '/sbin/nologin'},
                         {'user': {'name': 'kylie'}, 
                          'password': {'password': 'letmein'}, 
                          'permissions': [{'role': 'ADMINISTRATOR'}], 
                          'login_shell': '/sbin/bash'}])
b.Mgmt.UserMgmt.delete_user(['ron'])
```

The password is always a fixed value.The login shell value is decided by this dictionary :

```
find_shell = {'USER_ROLE_GUEST':'/sbin/nologin', 'OPERATOR':'/var/tmp', 'ADMINISTRATOR':'/sbin/bash'}
```

What I want is to loop through each line of the file,connect to the IP address,perform additon or deletion or skip the IP altogether(if no users to be added or deleted).This would ideally be done by me by using readlines(),split it into columns and then use the column index to perform the necessary operation.However,here the column length is not fixed.Apart from the first 2 columns which are always fixed,as is evident from the sample data,the remaining columns are always varying.What is the most ideal way of accomplishing this ?

Comment: why the negative vote ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
with open(filename) as file:
   input_data = file.readlines()

for line in input_data:
   columns = line.strip().split(' ')
   if len(columns)<3:
      continue
   device = columns[0]
   IP_address = columns[1]
   actions = columns[2:]
   open_connection(IP_address) #whatever this may be
   for action in actions:
      perform_action(action) #whatever this may be
```

If the first two columns are fixed, then columns[2:] will contain the commands you should execute. Just make sure you filter the case where you only have 2 columns.

You don't specifically need a dictionary to split your lines into columns.

Comment: @Daan..this is really nice..actions = columns[2:] is what i was specifically looking for..thanks